# install nltk on python

Tags: python, linux, pip, nltk

I tried to install `nltk` on terminal I have python2.7 and I installed python3.8 and java8 but i got a lot of errors

```
Last login: Wed Sep 30 22:02:28 on console
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % python -V
Python 2.7.16
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % sudo apt update
Password:
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % python3
Python 3.8.6 (v3.8.6:db455296be, Sep 23 2020, 13:31:39) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'

>>> 
zsh: suspended  python3
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % cd Desktop\python_Exercises
cd: no such file or directory: Desktoppython_Exercises
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % cd Desktop/python_Exercises
cd: no such file or directory: Desktop/python_Exercises
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % import sys
zsh: command not found: import
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % pyhton3.8
zsh: command not found: pyhton3.8
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % python3
Python 3.8.6 (v3.8.6:db455296be, Sep 23 2020, 13:31:39) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
zsh: suspended  python3
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.16
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % pip --version
pip 20.2.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2.3-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % python get-pip.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ % sudo apt install python3.8-pip
Password:
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
hanadyahmed@hanadys-mbp-2 ~ %
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is that it didn't install correctly. Could you explain the steps you took to install? That is probably where the issue lies.

Comment: Can you try `python3 -m pip install nltk` ?

Comment: I will try thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```py
import nltk

nltk.download()
```

This should bring up a window to select what you want to download from nltk

Comment: yes i tried this on both console and python 3.8 i will send to you the error message I got once I login from my laptop. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Try as @paxton4416 suggested. `pip3 install nltk`. And then open up `python3` and do the above

Answer (score 0):

Your default Python executable is your Mac's system Python, which as of MacOS 10.15 is still Python 2.7.16.  This means simply executing `python` will reference Python 2.7.16.  To reference your installation of Python 3.8.6, you need to call `python3`.  Similarly, **your two Python installations also have independent package managers**.  If you simply `pip install` a package, it will be installed for Python 2.7 in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.  To install a package that will be accessible to Python 3.8, you need to run `pip3 install <somepackage>`.